# Specific question construction (couldn’t find anything on Google)

Tags: grammaticality, questions

How do I ask why a person does not want a certain thing ?

If *why don’t you* is more like a suggestion, and *why you don’t wanna…*, as far as I know, is grammatically incorrect, what’s the correct way to say it? **Why won’t you want to… ** ??

Comment: This question will probably be better on the ELL site. In any event, you're looking for what is called the negative interrogative. Please avoid wanna etc. around here.  Why **don't you want to [verb].**

Comment: Go right ahead and write _wanna_; it's good English. But remember it means _want **to**_, not just _want_. You don't say *_I wanna that one, please,_ so you shouldn't write it.

Comment: "Why don't you" _can_ be a suggestion, but it doesn't have to be! "Why don't you want to come out with me tonight?" is a question, not a suggestion.

Comment: Question has now been duplicated on ELL.

Comment: @KateBunting I guess it was migrated (moved).

Comment: @gotube - You said that my answer doesn't address the question.  I think it does.  I think that splitting it up into two sentences accomplished the OP's goal.

Comment: @aparente001 - It seems the two have been merged since my last comment.

Answer (score 3):

***Why don't you X*** and ***Why don't you want to X*** are completely different in meaning.

**Examples**

**1.**

A: I'm tired

B: Why don't you lie down and rest for a while?

A: Yes - good idea

In this case "Why don't you lie down" is a polite suggestion - **it is an idiom, it is not a request for information**. Instead of telling someone "Lie down and rest!", which would appear rude, we ask "Why not?"

**2.**

A: I'm tired but I don't want to lie down

B: Why don't you want to lie down?

A: Because lying down would make my headache worse.

In this case, "Why don't you want" **is** a request for information. You have told me that you don't want to lie down and now I am enquiring the reason.

---

Note - Please avoid using "wanna". It's okay in text messages and social media but it should never be used in any kind of formal English.